# Счетчик в юнити

Tags: c#, unity3d

Нужно, чтобы при нажатии на UI панель в переменную , которая будет являться счетчиком, записывалось время в течение которого пользователь держит палец. Когда пользователь его отпустит, счетчик прекращает увеличиваться. Так же он увеличивается до тех пор, пока он не больше 3 секунд или пока пользователь не отпустил палец. Помогите написать код, который будет отвечать за сам счетчик. Условия нажатия включать не обязательно.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Самое простое решение, проверять, получить информацию о том, что пользователь сделал touch в методе `Update()`. И до тех пор, пока пользователь не убрал палец с экрана прибавлять к вашей переменной-счетчику времени значение [Time.deltaTime](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Time-deltaTime.html) и следите, чтобы оно не превышало 3, как вы писали в условии.

В итоге получите что-то вроде следующего:

```
    private bool touched;
    private float timer;

    private void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        {
            touched = true;
            return;
        }
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0))
            touched = false;
        if (touched)
        {
            timer += Time.deltaTime;
            if (timer > 3.0f) timer = 3.0f;
        }
    }
```